# Facebook OAuthException from only some servers

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a public Facebook photo album for display on a website.
I can access the list of photo albums and the individual albums using Facebook Graphc without getting an Access Token
see https://graph.facebook.com/vailresorts/albums
I've tried that from 4 different servers on different networks, none are logged on to facebook, and it works fine.  However, when I put it on my test server, it doesn't work and I get the

```
OAuthException - An access token is required to request this resource.
```

error.

I'm wondeirng why that is, requesting that url from different places give different results?

I was understanding that if the album is public, I don't need an App Id and App Secret.
Is this not true?

```
Request header:
    Request URL:https://graph.facebook.com/vailresorts/albums
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK
    Request Headersview source
    accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    accept-charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    cache-control:no-cache
    host:graph.facebook.com
    method:GET
    pragma:no-cache
    scheme:https
    url:/vailresorts/albums
    user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
version:HTTP/1.1

Comment: Have you inspected precisely what's being sent to facebook in the GET request, and are you positive that a token isn't actually being sent in the working cases? Can you post the full content of a working GET request?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not sending any token - I logged on to completely separate test server, installed Chrome, and typed in the URL above and got results.  I will edit above and put in the request header..

Comment: Well I changed to use an app id/secret to get this, but still makes no sense to me why it should work someplace but not others.

Comment: Hm, I'm getting different results as well. Sometimes it comes through, sometimes it doesn't. Trying to track down the difference.

Comment: ...and now I can't seem to get it to work at all. In some cases I was able to see albums and comments and usernames and ids, but now, nothing. I think I was copy/pasting the urls, but now I'm wondering what happened. Tried http and https - no difference.

Comment: yes I know, weird, isn't it?  Only thing I can think of is that facebook is throttling the results.

Comment: Yeah, not sure. The only thing I could find was the `album` resource, which isn't strictly the same, and which requires access tokens for any access: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ - possible they only recently changed the restrictions and you were hitting a different server each time, some of them updated and others not updated?

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in a 'me too' and the failures are not with every request. This bug may be related:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/410815249017032

I get the error:

{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}

Edit: sorry, didn't mean to answer, but wished to provide as a comment.  Ignorant yet on how to do that.

Update: I filed a new bug attempting to get their attention https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/444360005657309

Comment: good reference, good to know that it should work, but still is a bug apparently